# Is it possible to write the preimage of a Lebesgue integrable function as the union of nonmeasurable sets?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Is it possible to write the preimage of a Lebesgue integrable function as the union of nonmeasurable sets?

I guess this is sort of posed below in the opposite way:

Let's say $f$ is a lebesgue measurable function such that $f \neq 0$ for any $x$ in some arbitrary set $E$, and $m(E) > 0$. Can I gurantee that there exists sets $P \cup N = E$ such that $f > 0$ if $x \in P$ and $f < 0$ if $x \in N$ such that both sets are measurable? And if so, how?

---

**EDIT**: Suppose $f$ was originally defined on $\mathbb{R}^1$ of which $E$ is a measurable subset, with measure greater than zero.

Comment: A couple questions: What are the co-domain and domain of $f$. Where does $E$ live? What measure is $m$, I would assume Lebesgue measure?

Comment: One definition of $f$ being a Lebesgue measurable function means that the set $\{x \in D | f(x) > r\}$ is Lebesgue measurable as a set for all $r$ and $D$ is some measurable domain. Set $r = 0$ to get $P$. We also know by the definition that this is equivalent to $\{x  \in D| f(x) < r\}$ being Lebesgue measurable as a set for all $r$. Set $r =0$ to get N. These are both measurable sets.